# Does terminating a web worker also terminate any child workers it spawned?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

[The spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#terminate-a-worker) seems to indicate that it doesn't, but if I'm reading it correctly that seems like a pretty severe bug? It could lead to isolated workers wasting computational resources indefinitely, without the main program having any reference to them.

Answer (score 3):

Terminating a parent worker will kill the workers it did spawn.
What you describe is called "an orphan worker", and they are monitored to be closed. ([Temp. link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model:protected-worker))

> **Closing orphan workers:** Start monitoring the worker such that no sooner than it stops being a [protected worker](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#protected-worker), and no later than it stops being a [permissible worker](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#permissible-worker), worker global scope's closing flag is set to true.

And

> A worker is said to be a **protected worker** if it is an [active needed worker](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#active-needed-worker) and either it has outstanding timers, database transactions, or network connections, or its list of [the worker's ports](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#the-worker%27s-ports) is not empty, or its `WorkerGlobalScope` is actually a `SharedWorkerGlobalScope` object (i.e., the worker is a shared worker).

And also

> A worker is said to be an active needed worker if any [of] its [owners](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#concept-WorkerGlobalScope-owner-set) are either [Document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document) objects that are [fully active](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#fully-active) or [active needed workers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#active-needed-worker).

Because, when checking [the steps where the worker is created](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model) we can see that only the parent `WorkerGlobalScope` is ever added to the worker's *owner set*, when that parent worker is terminated, the nested one stops being an *active needed worker* and is thus being marked as *closing* and will be terminated after its current task is complete.

Comment: I suppose someone certainly *could* design a worker structure such that they want a grandchild worker to continue when the child is killed, but that seems odd. I'd expect that when I terminate a child, that means it can't affect anything anymore. I think ideally both options would be possible, there'd be a parameter you could pass to .terminate() or .close() that determines whether its children stick around.

Comment: Actually testing it again, it seems I was wrong and browsers do actually follow what the specs ask: they kill the nested workers even if it still performs observable tasks... I amend my answer.